# WebdriverIO -[ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]

Tags: webdriver-io

When I run my tests one at a time they work fine.

However, when I run in parallel (more than 2 at a time) I get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:266:14)
at RunnerStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:315:5)
at RunnerTransformStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:719:22)
at RunnerTransformStream.emit (events.js:314:20)
at RunnerTransformStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:298:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
at RunnerTransformStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
at RunnerTransformStream.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:152:32)
at RunnerTransformStream._transform (C:\dev\repositories\login.dfe.ui-tests\node_modules@wdio\local-runner\build\transformStream.js:15:14)
```

Anyone had this issue before?

Is it just running too fast?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this I changed legLevel in wdio.conf.js from 'info' to 'silent'.

That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Mind rising a properly described issue for this in github?